# List all existing tables in Azure Storage Account .NET core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How can I get all existing tables, which are created inside my Azure Storage account?

You used to do it like this

```
CloudTableClient tableClient;
IEnumerable<CloudTable> AllTables = tableClient.ListTables();
```

However it seems that I cannot call `ListTables` method on instance of `CloudTableClient`. I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Version 9.3.0`;

> EDIT

This is for .NET CORE

Comment: What’s the error you’re getting?

Comment: I am getting no error. I just simply cannot call it. Method closest to `ListTables` which I can call is `ListTablesSegmentedAsync`

Comment: Are you using Azure Storage SDK for .Net Core by any chance?

Comment: `Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.All (2.0.8)`

Comment: .NET Core doesn't yet include Sync Implementation of the APIs

Comment: I should have added it to my tag question, sorry.  So I cannot use that right ? Is there any convenient way to do it in .net core ?

Comment: Use `Async` methods available in the library.

Comment: I don't think there is a `ListTablesAsync()` either.. his best bet is to prefix his tables with something and use `ListTablesSegmentedAsync`

Comment: @JoshStevens Why did you delete your answer? You were on the right track IMHO. Can you explain what you mean by `his best bet is to prefix his tables with something `?

Comment: I accidentally deleted it - undid it straight away (was trying to edit).. have a look at my answer i explained it a little more

Comment: @JoshStevens Would you mind if I edit your answer?

Comment: I just expanded on it a little more.. but go ahead @GauravMantri

Comment: @JoshStevens Thanks! Edited your answer. Please feel free to make necessary changes.

Comment: ahh so if you pass in `null` to `ListTablesSegmentedAsync` it will list you every table without having to set a prefix? @GauravMantri

Comment: That's correct. Actually I used this override method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtableclient.listtablessegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTableClient_ListTablesSegmentedAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableContinuationToken_ which only takes a continuation token as a parameter. So what it will do is keep on looping until all tables are fetched.

Comment: Great I have refactored answer now so people can completely understand it! Cheers for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Go straight to the `EDIT` paragraph below if you looking for the .NET core answer

Well it seems like you are not creating an instance of `tableClient`

```
    CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    var AllTables = tableClient.ListTables();          
    if(AllTables != null)
    {
        foreach (var table in AllTables)
        {
            // table.Name is your property
        } 
    }
```

The method is on microsoft docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtableclient.listtables?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTableClient_ListTables_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_

> EDIT

further to this OP has just said they are using .NET CORE

**.NET Core doesn't yet include Sync Implementation of the APIs**

There is no method for `ListTables` so you have to use `ListTablesSegmentedAsync` and pass in null as the `continuationToken` parameter. This will keep on looping until all tables are fetched

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtableclient.listtablessegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTableClient_ListTablesSegmentedAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableContinuationToken_

**UPDATE EXAMPLE CODE**

Here's the pseudo code to list all tables

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
var allTables = new List<CloudTable>();
do
{
  var listingResult = await tableClient.ListTablesSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
  var tables = listingResult.Result.ToList();
  continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
  //Add the tables to your allTables
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

....

Comment: I doubt there will ever be a sync api. Since System.Runtime (Windows 8/Mobile Apps, which (the System.Runtiem) btw was the base for .NET Core microsoft went over to provide async apis only

Comment: Readers should pay close attention this [GitHub issue discussing missing syncronous methods for dotnet core](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367)